# Load Fullcalendar data base on Option selected from Dropdown

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

When i select person in the dropdown the FullCalendar will load the details he have in DB

I tried to call to another controller function but it gives me error because i didnt load the variables use in the index of the page

```html
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.js-example-basic-single').select2({

            });

            $('.js-example-basic-single').on('change', function(){
                var id = $('.js-example-basic-single').val();

                $.get('attendance/' + id,
                {'id':id}, 
                function(data){

                });
            });
            // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                // put your options and callbacks here
                plugins: [ 'interaction'],
                selectable: true,
                selectHelper: true,
                editable: true,
                events : [
                    @foreach($timesheet as $timesheets)
                    {
                        title : '{{ $timesheets->firstname . ' ' . $timesheets->lastname . ', ' . $timesheets->employee_id }}',
                        start : '{{ $timesheets->date }}',
                        color : 'green',
                        @if ($timesheets->date)
                                end: '{{ $timesheets->date }}',
                        @endif
                    },
                    @endforeach
                    @foreach($leave as $leaves)
                    {
                        title : '{{ $leaves->firstname . ' ' . $leaves->lastname . ', ' . $leaves->leave_type . ', ' . $leaves->leave_status }}',
                        start : '{{ $leaves->date_from }}T00:00:00',
                        @if ($leaves->date_to)
                                end: '{{ $leaves->date_to }}T24:00:00',
                        @endif
                    },
                    @endforeach
                ],
                dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view){
                    var attendance_date = date.format();

                    console.log(attendance_date);

                    $('#a_date').html(attendance_date);
                    $('#txt_a_date').val(attendance_date);
                },
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The last block of code works but it displays all data for all persons

Update: this is the my code now in conttroller and JS. It shows error of cannot read property hasTime of undefined

//Controller

```
    public function attendLoad(){


    $columns = [
        'date AS start',
        'date AS end',
        'employee_id AS id',
        'employee_id AS title' 
    ];
    $timesheets = TimeSheet::with('employee')->get($columns);
    $timesheet = $timesheets->toJson();

    return view('admin.attendance', compact('timesheet'));

  }

 ///JS
 events : [ 
                    {
                        url: '/attendances',
                        error: function() 
                        {
                            alert("error");
                        },
                        success: function()
                        {
                            console.log("successfully loaded");
                        }
                    }

            ],
```

Comment: P.S. you can make your code more dynamic / efficient / consistent by following the [events-as-json-feed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed) detailed in the fullCalendar docs. Instead of hard-coding the events using a foreach, simply specify a URL from where fullCalendar can retrieve the events. That URL should return the events in JSON format. It should accept, as input, start and end dates of the current calendar display, and also the user ID selected from the dropdown list.

Comment: Then whenever the "change" event occurs in the dropdown, simply call [refetchEvents](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchEvents) and fullCalendar will do the rest.

Comment: Hi sir i got an error. Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined

Comment: this is the result of dd in my controller that is called using the event feed

"[{"start":"2019-09-13","end":"2019-09-13","id":247,"title":"247-01","employee":null},{"start":"2019-09-13","end":"2019-09-13","id":247,"title":"247-01","employe ▶"

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with the data you've shown, although it appears to be an incomplete sample. Look out for missing or incomplete dates, that's the usual reason for that error. It could be anywhere in the code, not just the events

Comment: it works now i used this on event. 

events :  {!! $timesheet !!},

Im working now on the refetchEvents

Comment: `events : [ 
                    {
                        url: '/attendances` etc is wrong, events should not be an array when you are using an event source object inside it (instead of hard-coded events). Remove the `[` and `]` and that will work better.

Comment: when im using the url method it doesnt display the data in calendar. but it works if im using this code. `events :  {!! $timesheet !!},` . the problem is i cant load 2nd another event source

Comment: " the problem is i cant load 2nd another event source" ... switch to using the [eventSources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources) option instead of `events`, then.

Comment: P.S. If you use the URL method amended in the way I suggested (i.e. `events:
                    {
                        url: '/attendances',
                        error: function() 
                        {
                            alert("error");
                        },
                        success: function()
                        {
                            console.log("successfully loaded");
                        }
                    },` then it shouldn't cause any problems. You can always use the network tool to debug it if it does go wrong.